# Convert strings of varying pattern to date

Tags: string, postgresql, date

In our date column, there are so many different types of string. I am having trouble to convert all those to date type since patterns are not worked on DD-MM-YYYY and MM-DD-YYYY.

- 12/14/2015  MM/DD/YYYY;
- 19/07/2016    DD/MM/YYYY;
- 23.04.2016    DD.MM.YYYY;
- 1-6-2016     M-D-YYYY;
- 5-15-2016 M-DD-YYYY;
- 30-10-2016  DD-MM-YYYY;
- 8-6-2016  M-D-YYYY;

Or is there a more convenient way to do this?

Comment: you shouldn't have stored DATE values in a varchar column to begin with - then you wouldn't have that problem now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is ***no way at all*** to do this.

`8-6-2016` et al are irretrievably ambiguous without meta information. There is nothing to tell us which is month and day. If you have additional meta information available (did you save the pattern?), there might be a way out of this. Else, your case is lost.

Like a_horse commented: should have been [data type `date`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html) all along.